# How do PGP keys "expire"?

Tags: encryption, pgp, openpgp

When creating a PGP key, you can choose when the key "expires". What does this mean and how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your public key expires, it can't be used to encrypt.  When you generate your private/public keys, you should generate a revocation certificate so you can immediately revoke if needed...if you have no expiry time and no revocation certificate they can last forever.

As for how it works, quoting from https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c235.html :

> A key's expiration time is associated with the key's self-signature.
>   The expiration time is updated by deleting the old self-signature and
>   adding a new self-signature. Since correspondents will not have
>   deleted the old self-signature, they will see an additional
>   self-signature on the key when they update their copy of your key. The
>   latest self-signature takes precedence, however, so all correspondents
>   will unambiguously know the expiration times of your keys.

Comment: `if your public key expires` public key don't expire, certificates do. If the certificate expires, you can still do the encryption and signature verification math using the public key just as it was, and the recipient can still decrypt the data, however, it may just not be a good idea to do so, as the expiry is the date indicated by the key owner when you are supposed to re-verify the public key/certificate.